# Why won't parent/root binding throw an error when property is not defined

Tags: knockout.js

Why won't the following `parent` or `root` bindings cause knockout to crash:

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  child: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko with: child -->
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.bogus">
<input type="text" data-bind="text: $root.bogus">
<!-- /ko -->
```

...while this one...

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  child: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: bogus">
```

...and this one...

```js
ko.applyBindings({
  child: {}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-bind="text: bogus">
```

...do correctly crash knockout with error message 'bogus is not defined'?

I would've expected all of them to crash. Is there a reason the $parent/$root bindings shouldn't crash?

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the bindings inside an anonymous function like the one below, it doesn't crash -

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: function() {bogus}">
<input type="text" data-bind="text: function(){bogus}">
```

or inside a context switch like below

```
<!--ko with: child-->
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.bogus">
<input type="text" data-bind="text: $root.bogus">
<!--/ko-->
```

However, the moment you immediately call the function in the binding like below, it crashes -

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: function() {bogus}()">
<input type="text" data-bind="text: function(){bogus}()">
```

or even this -

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.bogus">
<input type="text" data-bind="text: $root.bogus">
```

So, with this it appears to me as if when wrapping the bindings around with a context switch like `with` (or may be `using`), the binding evaluation is deferred somehow to some point later.
While if not, the binding is evaluated at the time of DOM creation at the time of which `bogus` remains undefined.